# Spartacus 3.3 - How to extend default Storefront theme (Sparta)?

Tags: css, spartacus-storefront

Can someone suggest me which is the best way to extend the default Spartacus Storefront theme (Sparta) by overriding only the CSS var that I need to change?

I followed the guidelines at this URL: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontstyles/docs/flex-styling.md but none of the recommended methods seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sparta theme offers a lot of variables that can be overriden to customize the theme. All of them can be found in `@spartacus/styles/scss/theme/sparta/_variables`.

To override any SCSS variable just assign them to new value in your `styles.scss` file before Spartacus library import.

```
$primary: green;
$font-weight-normal: 600;

$styleVersion: 3.3;
@import "~@spartacus/styles/index";
```

Also Spartacus provides a stable set of variables, the CSS variables are mainly used for color schemes and font definitions
and it can be customized on the root of the document, or for specific selectors.

```
$styleVersion: 3.3;
@import "~@spartacus/styles/index";

:root {
  --cx-color-dark: red;
}
```

More information about Spartacus styling can be found here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/